# JQuery - Not Switching Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It is late so I hope that I am missing something simple.

I have a div that uses a font-awesome fa-plus symbol.  If clicked I want it to change to fa-minus and vice versa.
There is an additional class, add-team||remove-team, which is what the click event runs on.

It will change from + to - but not back to + when clicked a second time.

I have also done it from - to + and it doesn't change back to -.

Here is my div:

```
<div class="col-1 fa fa-plus add-team"></div>
```

And here are my simple jQuery lines:

```
$(".add-team").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("fa-minus remove-team").removeClass("fa-plus add-team");
});

$(".remove-team").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("fa-plus add-team").removeClass("fa-minus remove-team");
});
```

Hope that I'm just missing something simple.  Thanks.

Comment: Since there is no context to the code you have posted, it's very difficult to more than guess at what the problem is (but it could be that your click events are only attached to objects that **currently** have a particular class.  Try `$(document).on('click', '.add-team', ...` instead).  If that doesn't work, convert this into an [mcve]

Comment: Hava a look at the documentation regarding [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) and [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your event listeners are only set to listen to elements that currently have those classes. The listeners do not dynamically change when the element's classes change. So since the element starts with `add-team` only the `add-team` listener is going to work.

What you can do is use setup a [delegate event listener](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), a listener that is setup on a parent element that does not change, eg `document` and run the listeners off of that.

```
$(document).on('click','.add-team',function(){
   //...
});
$(document).on('click','.remove-team',function(){
   //...
});
```

But you can also just use a single event listener and use [jQuery's toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) to toggle all the classes in one call

```
$(this).toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus add-team remove-team");
```

Demo

```js
$(".col-1").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus add-team remove-team");
});
```

```css
.col-1 {
  font-size:24px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.fa-plus:after {
  content:'+';
}
.fa-minus:after {
  content:'-';
}
.add-team {
  color:green;
}
.remove-team {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-1 fa fa-plus add-team"></div>
```